# Long sorted dropdown list with WTForms

Tags: python, forms, wtforms

I'd like to create a drop-down list of the U.S. states in alphabetical order.  I've converted a tuple of states into an OrderedDict and I'm feeding this into my WTForms SelectField.

```
import collections
import wtforms

STATE_ABBREV = ('AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 
                'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 
                'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 
                'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 
                'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY')

def list_to_ordered_pairs(input_list):
    ordered_pairs = collections.OrderedDict()
    for item in input_list:
        ordered_pairs[item] = item
    return ordered_pairs

state_pairs = list_to_ordered_pairs(STATE_ABBREV)

class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
    state = wtforms.SelectField(label='State', choices=state_pairs)
```

My problem is that the resulting dropdown menu shows only the second letter of each state...

[image: Dropdown]

How do I fix this up to show the proper two-letter designation?  And is there a better approach to pulling in various geographic regions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There are a few issues here:

**Your list isn't a list its a 50-tuple.**

```
STATE_ABBREV = ('AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 
                'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 
                'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 
                'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 
                'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY')
```

If you wanted a list, it would look something like:

```
STATE_ABBREV = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 
                'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 
                'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 
                'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 
                'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
```

**I don't believe your `state_pairs` are pairs in the sense that you think they are. They are pairs like this**

```
>>> state_pair = 'AK'
>>> abbr, state = state_pair
>>> print abbr
A
>>> print state
K
>>>
```

I believe `state_pair` you want would look something like this:

```
>>> state_pair = ('AK', 'Alaska')
>>> abbr, state = state_pair
>>> print abbr
AK
>>> print state
Alaska
>>>
```

The solution to the problem you are seeing is to get rid of the method `list_to_ordere_pair` and just create a list of of `state_pairs`

```
STATE_CHOICES = [('AL', 'Alabama'),('AK','Alaska')...]

class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
    state = wtforms.SelectField(label='State', choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and explanation.  I ended up using this -- class MyForm(wtforms.Form): state = wtforms.SelectField(label='State', choices=zip(STATE_ABBREV, STATES)) where I made a separate 50-tuple for the states.

Answer (score 6):

The WTForms docs call for the choices property to be a sequence of (value, label) pairs.  I mistakenly read this as key value pairs and was trying to use a dictionary.  This simple list comprehension does the trick...

```
import wtforms

STATE_ABBREV = ('AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 
                'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 
                'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 
                'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 
                'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY')

class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
    state = wtforms.SelectField(label='State', 
        choices=[(state, state) for state in STATE_ABBREV])
```