# wtforms: dropdown selector with values defined in model class

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I would like to create a model for flask-wtforms where the values of the dropdown selectors are defined in the model already, as they are always the same. I tried the following:

```
class DroppdownForm(Form):
    fields = {}
    df = pd.read_excel(open('formfile.xlsx', 'rb'), sheetname='Sheet1')

    df.fillna(value='NA', inplace=True)
    form_fields = ['COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2', 'COLUMN3']

    for form_field_name in form_fields:
        fields[form_field_name] = SelectField(form_field_name, sorted(df[form_field_name].unique().tolist()), description=form_field_name)
```

the view:

```
def show_entries():
    form=DroppdownForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

When I then render it in the html file with

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}

 {% for field in form %}
     {{ render_field(field) }}
 {% endfor %}
```

The form is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does my answer help? If not I would  like to help further.

Comment: I think your answer is too generic. In my code you can see that I generate a selectfield in a for loop in the model file but for some reason it doesn't work. Could it be connected to the fact that I put it into a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

the view:

```
from wtforms import Form, SelectField
import pandas as pd

def DroppdownFormGen(**kwargs):

    class DroppdownForm(Form):
        pass

    df = pd.read_excel(open('MOCK_DATA.xlsx', 'rb'), sheetname='data')
    df.fillna(value='NA', inplace=True)
    form_fields = ['COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2', 'COLUMN3']

    for form_field_name in form_fields:
        label = form_field_name
        field = SelectField(label,choices=list(zip(range(5),sorted(df[form_field_name].unique().tolist()))))
        setattr(DroppdownForm, label, field)

    return DroppdownForm(**kwargs)       


@app.route('/form', methods=['GET'])      
def show_entries():
    form=DroppdownFormGen()
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```

the template:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

<form method=post action="">

 {% for field in form %}
     {{ render_field(field) }}
 {% endfor %}

  <p><input type=submit value='Submit'>
</form>
```

where _formhelpers.html is here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/wtforms/

plus

```
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 2

    def __init__(self, i_var):
        self.instance_var = i_var

setattr(MyClass, 'a', 'value-of-a-field')

foo = MyClass(5)
bar = MyClass(6)

print(foo.class_var, foo.instance_var, foo.a)
# 2 5 value-of-a-field
print(bar.class_var, bar.instance_var, bar.a)
# 2 6 value-of-a-field
print(MyClass.a) 
# value-of-a-field
print(MyClass.class_var)
# 2
```

Comment: Why does it make a difference if I do if I do form=DropdownFormGen() or form=DropdownForm()?

Comment: When I set setattr(DroppdownForm, label, field) DroppdownForm is already defined, I could not handle this issue without wrapping the form in a function.

Comment: It works but I don't understand what setattr is doing exactly. Is it creating multiple instances of DroppdownForm? How are they then kept together and returned by the function?

Comment: I added a simple example of setattr usage

Comment: Ok I get it now. So it's essentially setting class variables. While I see that this works, wouldn't there be a more elegant way to solve this with a dictionary somehow instead of having to create a new class variable for each field?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic way you can get a dropdown form. You can process you data into a list of tuples with `value` and `label`.

```
class DropDown(Form):
    fields = [(value, label), (value, label), (value, label)...]
    dropdown = SelectField('Mydropdown', choices = fields)
```

[Select Field Wtforms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)

[Check out this for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016093/5465739)